# Insert Data retrieved from another row except one updated column

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, sqldatasource, formview

I would like to take all the data used in a previous row and insert it into a new row. However, in one column I will be using a new value. I am using a `SqlDataSource` in a `FormView` to show this information once completed. Is there a way to handle this?

For example,

Old table

```
DataID    StartDate    EndDate
112       2014-05-01   2014-06-02
```

New table

```
DataID    StartDate    EndDate
112       2014-05-01   2014-06-02
113       2014-05-01   2014-06-02
```

I am using this query to increment the `DataID`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    (SELECT MAX (DataID) + 1 
     FROM Core.DataCollectionPeriod) AS DataID 
FROM Core.DataCollectionPeriod
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8145f/1/0)):

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
(StartDate, EndDate)
SELECT TOP 1 StartDate, EndDate
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY Dataid Desc;
```

Comment: Is there a way to get around the error "cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF? Without actually having to make changes to the properties of the table?

Comment: **@user3339242**, yes just leave the `DataID` field out of the insert statement.  It will automatically increment by 1 anyway.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Question, when I delete the values from the Database and insert them in again the DataID number keeps increasing. I.e 115,116. I deleted the newly created row so why isnt it staying at 113?

Comment: `DataID` will always increment by 1 if inserting a new record since it is set as an **IDENTITY** field.  Regardless of if there are records in the table or not.  To resent it see [**DBCC CHECKIDENT**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057%28SQL.90%29.aspx).